# In Django, how can I get an exception's message?

Tags: python, django, exception

In a view function, I have something like:

```
try:
    url = request.POST.get('u', '')
    if len(url) == 0:
        raise ValidationError('Empty URL')
except ValidationError, err:
    print err
```

The output is a string: `[u'Empty URL']`

When I try to pass the error message to my template (stuffed in a dict, something like `{ 'error_message': err.value }`), the template successfully gets the message (using `{{ error_message }}`).

The problem is that I get the exact same string as above, `[u'Empty URL']`, with the `[u'...']`!

How do I get rid of that?

(Python 2.6.5, Django 1.2.4, Xubuntu 10.04)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ValidationError` actually holds multiple error messages.

The output of `print err` is `[u'Empty URL']` because that is the string returned by `repr(err.messages)` (see `ValidationError.__str__` source code).

If you want to print a single readable message out of a `ValidationError`, you can concatenate the list of error messages, for example:

```
    # Python 2 
    print '; '.join(err.messages)
```

```
    # Python 3
    print('; '.join(err.messages))
```

Comment: I figured that, as validators for a field is also an array. Good to know about the `messages` member of `ValidationError`. They never mention it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/ as they primarily should!

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing `ValidationError` from `django.core.exceptions` you can simply use `messages` method as `err.messages`.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/exceptions.py#L124

If you are importing `ValidationError` from `rest_framework.serializers` , there is no `messages` property for the `ValidationError` but there is `detail` property. so you can use `err.detail` which will give you a dictionary.

In order to concatenate all the error messages as a string, you can use
`"".join(["".join(v) for v in err.detail.values()])`
or
`"".join([k+" - "+"".join(v) for k,v in err.detail.items()])`

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L143

Answer (score 0):

A more general way to always know where the message is to call the `dir` function on your `err` variable to show you all the attribute of this object.
from that list you can infer where the messages are, in my case (with *django 3.2*) i found out that the message dict is in an attribute called `args`.
so to use it (with a print for example)

```py
try:
    url = request.POST.get('u', '')
    if len(url) == 0:
        raise ValidationError('Empty URL')
except ValidationError, err:
    print(err.args) # HERE THE ERROR DICT MESSAGE IS ACCESSIBLE
```

Answer (score -5):

I fixed it by changing `ValidationError` to `BaseException`.

Comment: That is actually bad practise I'd say. BaseException catches everything, whereas you should only handle ValidationError. If another exception pops it's because there's an error in your code, which should be fixed.

Comment: Well, I did raise the error/exception myself.  The code in the `try` block was _very_ minimal, that I thought the chances of a different kind of error popping up was slim.  I just wanted to reuse `ValidationError` for semantic purposes.  I guess the more proper approach would be to subclass `BaseException` with my own kind of validation error?  In any case, the code has changed a lot since I first posted this and my workaround is no longer applicable, so I accepted the answer above instead.